# Can I create a constant from a symbol and use it as array initializer?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

Basically I want to create the data IR for following C code:

```
extern int myarr1[];
int myarr2 = {(int)&myarr1, 0, 0};
```

So I created an `llvm::GlobalVariable` object for `myarr1`. But `llvm` asserted out and said it can't be used as an initializer.

> Wrong type in array element initializer

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

llvm::Constant *cons = ConstantExpr::getCast(Instruction::PtrToInt, gvar_array_myarr1, IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 32));

Thanks!